# 'Unspecified certificate from client' error received from Delphi THTTPClient post request in ver 10.3.1 but not 10.3.2

Tags: json, delphi, certificate, httpclient

As the title suggests, I'm receiving this error when trying to make a simple POST request via a `THTTPClient` in Delphi and the connection isn't completed so I get no response:

```pascal
lHttpResp := FHTTP.Post(
  'https://url123/',
  jsonToSend,
  nil,
  [
    TNetHeader.Create('content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf8'),
    TNetHeader.Create('accept', 'application/json;charset=utf8')
  ]);
```

This call works without an issue when built with Delphi 10.3.2 / Windows 10.

I thought perhaps copying the 10.3.2 `\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\rtl` files to the 10.3.1 machine might have done the trick, alas it didn't.

Upgrade is an option, however it would be nice if there was a simple code fix/work around for 10.3.1.

**Edit:** I thought this might help, however it didn't: [Unspecified certificate from client when using TRESTRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106557/)

How do I get this working in 10.3.1?

Comment: No question here. Do you just want to silence any error (just as the answer in the linked question does) or do you want to fix what fails for the S in HTTPS?

Comment: There is a question because the error prevents a connection.

Comment: There's nowhere a question mark and even in your comment you haven't decided on what you actually want - you only outline your problem.

Comment: Thanks AmigoJack, I've made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to just upgrade to a version >= 10.3.2